# Webpack replacing external import object with object.default

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm writing a chrome extension using typescript with webpack to create the final javascript output file. I would like the extension to rely on a global instance of the external library `Konva` defined in the browser.

My typescript code is something like:

```
import Konva from "Konva";

for(const shp in Konva.shapes) {
   //Do something
}
```

Webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: '/content/init.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    externals: {
        "Konva": "Konva"
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'dist.min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    },
}
```

I'm then creating a `<script></script>` element with a reference to the dist.min.js file and adding it to the page.

When I look at the dist.min.js file, I see that the reference to `Konva` is effectively replaced with:

```
for(const t in s.default.shapes){ //equivalent to Konva.default.shapes
    //Do something
}
```

where `s` points to the global instance of Konva.

However, I'm looking for just

```
for(const t in s.shapes) { //equivalent to Konva.shapes
    //Do something
}
```

Since `s.default` is undefined.

It seems like webpack is replacing the instance to my external library `object` with `object.default`. Is there anyway I can disable this?

I've tried messing with [externalsType](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstype) as well as an [IgnorePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/) without success. This is my first time working with typescript and webpack so I'm out of ideas for what to google next.